# Call functions within a python script and pass arguments using command line

Tags: python-2.7, function, parameters

- I have a script named first_code.py
- The code in the script looks like

def function1(param1):
    return var1
def function2(param1):
    return var2
def function3(param1):
    return var3

I want to execute the script first_code.py from the windows command like and pass the value of the param1 such that: all the functions get executed or if I want to execute a specific function say function2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to have a more generalized way to call a function the takes 0-* params :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print (len(sys.argv))
   params = []
   if len(sys.argv) > 2:
      for x in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
         params.append(sys.argv[x])
   if len(params) > 0:
      globals()[sys.argv[1]](*params)
   else:
      globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

If your script 'getstuff.py' included a function named 'getSomething(forWho, fromWho)' it
can be called:
      python getstuff.py getsomething "Ray" "Steve"

Can take as many parameters as you want.

Just include the snippet in you script.:>)

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you specify in command line are kept in [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)
you should add the following lines in the bottom of the code:

```
print function1(sys.argv[1])
print function2(sys.argv[1])
print function3(sys.argv[1])
```

please note sys.argv[0] is the script name.

If you want to specify the functions to be run add more arguments, they will be in `sys.argv[2]`, `sys.argv[3]` etc'